# SQL: Is it possible to calculate field by formula inside another field as text

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to make table or view, that have filed calculation by formula
,that specified in other field as text?

for example:

```
    A     B     C    formula    value
-   -     -     -   --------    -----
1.  2     1     3    (A+B)*C      9
2. 100   null   2      A/C       50
```

thanks and best regards

Comment: Maybe with a CLR function, using a parsing library. The closest you could get in T-SQL would be a CASE statement but in that case you'd need to know the formula variations at design time.

Comment: I think that a function would do just fine. You just get the column names from the formula field and create a dynamic sql with it. It would work without the need of any parsing.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, you mean create a function and use Dynamic SQL inside the function ?

Comment: @Squirrel Yes, I've tried but deleted my answer. Don't have sqlserver to test it here.

Answer (score 1):

This was interesting to think about. I am not really sure this is the most efficient way of doing it, but here's a solution that does work...

```
CREATE TABLE tmpMaths (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), A INT, B INT, C INT, formula VARCHAR(255), formulaResult FLOAT);
INSERT tmpMaths (A, B, C, formula) VALUES (2, 1, 3, '(A+B)*C')
, (100, NULL, 2, 'A/C/C/C/A');

DECLARE @Results TABLE (ID INT, Result FLOAT);
DECLARE @SQL2 VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @SQL2 += ' UNION ALL SELECT ' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(255)) + ' ID, 1.0 * ' 
    + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(formula, 'A', ISNULL(A, '')), 'B', ISNULL(B, '')), 'C', ISNULL(C, '')) 
    + ' Result FROM tmpMaths WHERE ID = ' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(255))
FROM tmpMaths;
SELECT @SQL2 = STUFF(@SQL2, 1, 11, '');
INSERT @Results (ID, Result)
EXEC(@SQL2);

UPDATE M SET formulaResult = R.Result --SELECT M.ID, A, B, C, formula, Result
FROM tmpMaths M
JOIN @Results R ON R.ID = M.ID;

SELECT * FROM tmpMaths;

DROP TABLE tmpMaths;
```

If you don't know all the column names, something like the following is a bit more convoluted but works anyway... (Essentially it gets the column names via dynamic SQL):

```
CREATE TABLE tmpMaths (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), A INT, B INT, C INT, formula VARCHAR(255));
INSERT tmpMaths (A, B, C, formula) VALUES (2, 1, 3, '(A+B)*C')
, (100, NULL, 2, 'A/C/C/C/A');

DECLARE @replacecount INT = (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tmpMaths'
    AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('ID', 'formula')) -- get the count of columns, unnecessary if it's always just 3 (A, B, C)
, @replace VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
, @cols VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @replace += ', ''' + COLUMN_NAME + ''', ISNULL(' + COLUMN_NAME + ', ''''))' -- for replacing the column names in the formula
     , @cols += ', ' + COLUMN_NAME -- for selecting the columns in output, unnecessary if it's always just A, B, C
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tmpMaths'
AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('ID', 'formula');

DECLARE @selectreplace NVARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE('REPLACE(', @replacecount) + 'formula' + @replace; -- e.g. REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(formula, 'A', A), 'B', B), 'C' C)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpEvaluated') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpEvaluated;
CREATE TABLE #tmpEvaluated (ID INT, Evaluated VARCHAR(255));
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = 'INSERT #tmpEvaluated (ID, Evaluated) SELECT ID, ' + @selectreplace + ' FROM tmpMaths';
EXEC(@SQL); -- produces the formula with numbers instead of column names

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpResults') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmpResults;
CREATE TABLE #tmpResults (ID INT, Result FLOAT);
DECLARE @SQL2 VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @SQL2 += ' UNION ALL SELECT ' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(255)) + ' ID, 1.0 * ' + Evaluated + ' Result FROM #tmpEvaluated WHERE ID = ' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(255))
FROM #tmpEvaluated;
SELECT @SQL2 = STUFF(@SQL2, 1, 11, '');
INSERT #tmpResults (ID, Result)
EXEC(@SQL2); -- gets the result of the formula with numbers in it (a series of UNION ALL statements)
PRINT @SQL2;

DECLARE @output VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT M.ID' + @cols + ', formula, result FROM tmpMaths M JOIN #tmpResults R ON R.ID = M.ID';
EXEC(@output);

DROP TABLE tmpMaths;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you it was helpful but i need a way to do this from in the table or by view so for any time i open the table or the view i can see the update value

Comment: p.s. i know the column names

Comment: it can be very help if you can help me convert the query to ms access query

Comment: To make it a view, just CREATE VIEW X AS... and then add the appropriate query. To put it in a table, just update the table from the query (for example, `UPDATE M SET columnX = Result...` in the select statement at the end - I added an example of this in the answer). As for converting it to an Access query, Access doesn't really allow dynamic SQL - you'd do it through something else (e.g. VB).

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure abcf, Line 2 [Batch Start Line 0]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DECLARE'.
Msg 4508, Level 16, State 1, Procedure abcf, Line 18 [Batch Start Line 0]
Views or functions are not allowed on temporary tables. Table names that begin with '#' denote temporary tables.
Msg 4508, Level 16, State 1, Procedure abcf, Line 19 [Batch Start Line 0]
Views or functions are not allowed on temporary tables. Table names that begin with '#' denote temporary tables.
................................

Comment: Right. Sorry, I wasn't thinking. Your easiest option is to update the results column of your table (or if you don't have a results column, add one with something like `ALTER TABLE tblName ADD Results FLOAT`, update it from the query, and create a view of the table.